# System.getProperty unable to read from a particular environment variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a particular variable that is named xxx_home in the environment that is located under

```
....\Documents\NetBeansProjects\....
```

I've tested with my Java_home and other variables which are all readable except this particular xxx_home variable. As the location of this variable is in d

I'm reading it using the following code which returns null for xxx_home

```
String homePath = System.getProperty("xxx.home");
        System.out.println(homePath);
```

[My environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olh5V.png)

When I attempt to test it via CMD with echo %XXX_HOME%, it returns the correct value. Appreciate any help!

CMD returns correct value, other values in the environment variable is retrievable via the same code

Update:

1. The spelling of xxx.home and `System.getProperty("xxx.home");` is the same
2. I'm not able to change the code `System.getProperty("xxx.home")`
3. I'm able to read JAVA_HOME from environment variables -> user variables with `System.getProperty("java.home")` just fine

Comment: Not much point showing us an obfuscated picture of a variable, but xxx.home != xxx_home

Comment: In my environment variable, I have my jdk set as JAVA_HOME, using System.getProperty("java.home"); I can get the directory, is this not how it is suppose to work?

Comment: System property != environment variable. Use `System.getenv("xyz")` to read an environment variable, and `System.getProperty("xyz");` to read a system property

Comment: I need to use getProperty due to restrictions in the project, both xxx_home and JAVA_HOME is under the user variables section and I can read JAVA_HOME just fine with getProperty

Comment: Launch your java application passing "-Dxxx.home=%XXX_HOME%" on the command line

Comment: Or, to make it work with your *current* code, you could do `"-Dxxx.home=%XXX_HOME%" `

Comment: Getting null still, I've put it under program arguments in intellij, I think I'm doing it right? Could it be a security policy issue on my laptop? I'm using company laptop and none of my other team members have the same issue

Comment: Enumerate over all items within the collection returned by System.getProperties() and check what's there

Comment: As @DuncG has said, you can access directly with `System.getenv("XXX_HOME");`

Comment: @WilliamLee " I can read JAVA_HOME just fine with getProperty". You are mistaken: Java sets system property "java.home" based on the current running VM, isn't the value of JAVA_HOME environment variable. If you launch say "c:\jdk-17\bin\java" and "c:\jdk-21\bin\java" then each VM sets  system property "java.home" appropriately

Comment: *Java sets system property "java.home" based on the current running VM,* Thank you @DuncG, I'd forgotten to correct that

Comment: @g00se yes getenv works, thanks!

Comment: Good, but @DuncG mentioned it first ;)

Comment: @g00se it looks like Using system.getproperty("%XXX_HOME%") doesn't work, is there a way I can define XXX_HOME such that I can use System.getproperty("xxx.home") to retrieve the directory? Instead of using getenv

Comment: Well I already told you how to do that above. But of course you need to ensure you set that VM parameter in your run configuration in Netbeans. Personally, I don't know how to do that. Personally I wouldn't do this. If you have *already* set an environment variable, why give yourself the *extra* step of also setting it(then retrieving it)  as a VM parameter?

Comment: I have set -Dxxx.home=%XXX_HOME%, so that means when System.getproperty("xxx.home") runs, it should actually be running system.getproperty("%XXX_HOME%") right? 

I can't change the code of the project but I can change the configuration of my IDE/setup. I already have -Dxxx.home=%XXX_HOME% in my VM parameter, System.getproperty("xxx.home") still doesn't work

Comment: The problem could be that `%XXX_HOME%` is expanded by the shell and that might not happen with Netbeans. You'd probably be better off telling us what your logical goal is here. e.g. if it's using a certain directory relative to a fixed one then there could be a better way. Also, defining stuff in relation to your NB projects directory is suspect and probably shouldn't be happening

Comment: I tried in intellij as well for -Dxxx.home=%XXX_HOME% which returns null, but in Netbeans it returns %XXX_HOME% which was weird. The code in the project is System.getproperty("xxx.home") and I need this code to return the value ( directory of resources ) I set in the environment variable for XXX_HOME

Comment: *but in Netbeans it returns %XXX_HOME% which was weird.* Not weird at all, but for the reason I just gave. As I suspected, you're doing this all wrong. Resources are nothing to do with file system paths. [You need to rethink](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)

Comment: Resources are contained in the deployment unit, not in the file system